# how do i convert my API hosted in remoting to WCF

Tags: wcf

i have a API which is hosted using Remoting for security and creating a business logic which is shared among all my other applications
now i want to convert this API into WCF do i need to rewrite it or is there any option available

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some great resources out there on the web for this topic:

- [From .NET Remoting to the Windows Communication Foundation (WCF)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730857%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)
- [Migrating .NET Remoting to WCF (and even ASMX!)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mattavis/archive/2005/10/10/479280.aspx)

And a lot more - just Google or Bing for them!

Answer (score 0):

Given that your application is "layered" - so the business logic resides in its own classes - this should be fairly straightforward.

Good places to start to learn WCF are MSDN here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734712.aspx and the "fish book", "Programming WCF Services", here: http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596526993.do